# unable to locate postgresql in etc centos

Tags: postgresql, centos, postgresql-9.1

I tried installing `postgresql` in my server which has centos

I followed [this link](http://opensourcedbms.com/dbms/installing-postgresql-9-2-on-cent-os-6-3-redhat-el6-fedora/)

I am facing few complexity here.

1. I could not locate postgresql file in `/etc` directory.
2. psql (8.4.13, server 9.2.4) WARNING: psql version 8.4, server version 9.2. Some psql features might not work.

How can i solve these issues. can anyone suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> I could not locate postgresql file in /etc directory.
> ```

The tutorial you linked to suggests the config files are in /var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/...

> ```
> psql (8.4.13, server 9.2.4) WARNING: psql version 8.4, server version 9.2. Some psql features might not work.
> ```

You've still got the 8.4 version of psql installed. Use your package tools (rpm/yum) to see what versions of the psql client packages are installed and where the binaries are.

It's common enough to run two different versions of PG on the same machine. Obviously each needs its own data directory and port number. Also, as you've seen psql will check the version number and warn if they are different. Basic queries still work, but obviously an 8.4 version won't know about extensions introduced in 9.1 and that sort of thing.